# Сформировать список элементов из нескольких списков элементов других типов

Tags: c#, .net

у меня имеется 3 списка с различными типами объектов, которые они содержат. Из них мне нужно сформировать единый список, который бы содержал часть данных из этих списков, такие как, к примеру - ID, Дату создания, ItemId(ссылка на список, из которого были взяты данные.

Вот что я делаю:

```
var posts = _postRepository.GetFiltered(new DataFilter{});

var rewards = _rewardRepository.GetFiltered(new DataFilter{});

var challengesWon = _challengePartRepository.GetFiltered(new DataFilter{});
```

где GetFiltered - метод, который делает выборку данных по определённому критерию, содержащемуся в DataFilter

Вопрос в том, как теперь из них сформировать List с нужными мне данными и записать его в БД.
Заранее спасибо

Comment: Если вы хотите записать результат в БД, то, судя по всему, у вас уже есть модель под это дело. Почему бы вам сразу не заполнить эту модель из ваших списков, заполняя одну и туже коллекцию или конкатенируя результат трех преобразований

Comment: @morphey83, да, вы правы - модель есть. Не могли бы вы подсказать как это сделать ? Был бы очень признателен

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
    var posts = _postRepository
        .GetFiltered(new DataFilter { })
        .Select(it => new MyModel{ A = it.A });

    var rewards = _rewardRepository
        .GetFiltered(new DataFilter { })
        .Select(it => new MyModel{A = it.A});

    var challengesWon = _challengePartRepository
        .GetFiltered(new DataFilter { })
        .Select(it => new MyModel{ A = it.A });

    var result = posts
        .Concat(rewards)
        .Concat(challengesWon)
        .ToList();
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо тебе!